# Save image in a rectangle

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to save image in a rectangle filled red but I got a file which is not an image this is my code:

```
protected void btnDrowRect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    string fn1 = Session["WorkingImage"].ToString();

    string imagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Images/rec" + fn1);
    string savetoo = Server.MapPath("~/Images/rect/rec" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss"));
   string imageNewPath = savetoo; ;

    Image image = Image.FromFile(imagePath);

    int a = Int32.Parse(imgw.Value) / 2 - img3.Width / 2;
    int b = Int32.Parse(imgh.Value) / 2 - img3.Height / 2;

    Rectangle srcRect = new Rectangle(-a, -b, Int32.Parse(imgw.Value),Int32.Parse(imgh.Value));
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Int32.Parse(imgw.Value), Int32.Parse(imgh.Value));
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        // Create image.
        Image newImage = Image.FromFile(imagePath);

        // Create rectangle for displaying image.
        Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Int32.Parse(imgw.Value), Int32.Parse(imgh.Value));

        // Create rectangle for source image.

        GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

        Color customColor = Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Red);
        SolidBrush shadowBrush = new SolidBrush(customColor);
        g.FillRectangles(shadowBrush, new RectangleF[] { destRect });

        // Draw image to screen.
        g.DrawImage(newImage, destRect, srcRect, units);
        // g.Save();

    }

    bmp.Save(imageNewPath);

}
```

Click here to see the file that was saved :

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nso3c.png

But I want to be saved like this:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7CUl.png

Comment: `http://i.stack.imgur.com/Nso3c.png` is borken.

Comment: int a = Int32.Parse(imgw.Value) / 2 - img3.Width / 2;
int b = Int32.Parse(imgh.Value) / 2 - img3.Height / 2;
What is imgh, imgw and img3? it is no where defined

Comment: They're completely different images.. What exactly is `like this` specifying? The image is wrong? The size is wrong? You want the pink borders? Don't just dump code with vague text and expect people to figure out what you need...

Comment: imgw and imgh are the original image width and height

Comment: Kindly use a better **Title** than the one you have used. Add title that relates to your actual problem.

Comment: You should give the extension of the file as well `string savetoo = Server.MapPath("~/Images/rect/rec" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss") + ".jpg");` and while saving it would be `bmp.Save(imageNewPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);`

Comment: thanks alot @MohitShrivastava it works great :)

Comment: Posted as an answer. So that you can accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
string savetoo = Server.MapPath("~/Images/rect/rec" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hhmmss") + ".jpg");
```

and

```
bmp.Save(imageNewPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

And it will be working